# Netbeans, ROS and debug

Tags: ros, catkin, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I want to develop and debug packages in ROS with Netbeans. I followed the Instructions at [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) but I have some questions:

catkin_make is creating all his stuff inside my `myworkspace/build/mypackage` (caktin, catkin_generated, MakeFile, etc.) and the executable in `myworkspace/devel/lib/mypackage`

but if I do it with Netbeans, all this stuff is inside `myworkspace/src/mypackage`.

Is this a problem (e.g., ambiguity during compiling/running)?

When I compile with Netbeans and then with `catkin_make` rosrun says that there are two executables and I have to choose. Is there a way to do something clean (e.g., putting all catkin/cmake/make stuff in a separate folder and the executable in a folder like `mypackage/bin` even if I call catkin_make on the workspace? Why catkin is forcing us to have one place to compile all the packages in a folder far from them?

**EDIT:**
After losing so much time I ended with this solution (I hope will be appreciated):

File -> New Project -> New Project with existing source

Next

In the folder with existing source `myworkspace/src/mypackage`

Custom

Next

configure script: `myworkspace/src/CMakeLists.txt` This is the GLOBAL cmakefile of ROS, not the package one

configure arguments: `-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=myworkspace/devel` **WITH ABSOLUTE PATH**

run the configure script in subfolder: `../build` so that he's pointing to the global build space

Next until the end

This is the best I could. If anybody knows a CLEAN method to specify programmatically where to put Build Space, Devel Space and Install space inside the project CMakeLists.txt, please tell me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153591/netbeans,-ros-and-debug/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those instructions sounds pretty specific to `rosmake`, so they probably aren't designed to work with `catkin`. I don't use Netbeans so I might not get all this right, but it seems to me the biggest change is that you need to tell Netbeans to run CMake in `myworkspace/build/package` rather than in `myworkspace/src/package` where it is now. There may be other issues involved, but that would be the first thing.

If you are working on a single package then you can treat it like a plain cmake package and these instructions will likely work:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8027379

This doesn't allow it to work with a catkin workspace, but it is a step in the right direction.

If you are using `catkin_make` then you'll have a boilerplate `CMakeLists.txt` in `myworkspace/src`, so if you point Netbeans at that "CMake project" then you can mimic the behavior of `catkin_make` by:

- running `cmake` in `myworkspace/build`
- passing `-DCATKIN_DEVEL_SPACE=../devel` to `cmake`
- passing `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install` to `cmake`

Maybe some of that helps.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-04-17**:
I found your solution reasonable. I tried it but there's something wrong. Since Netbeans oblige me to run the cmake only on a subfolder of myworkspace/src/mypackage I created a soft link that points to myworkspace/build/mypackage and effectively all the stuff is going into the right place. But then cmake says that there's no Cmakelists.txt to process, looking for it inside myworkspace/build even if I never told that path to it...